How select all elements with same attribute value
If i using [class~="logo"] { padding: 2px; } it will select all element that have contain logo in class attribute value. (Like <element class="logo-idk">) But how if i want to select all attribute that contain logo value?
Maybe like [all-attributes~="logo"] {   padding: 2px; }, so it will apply to all attribute that have contain logo. Like <a class="logo">, <a id="logo">, <a custom="logo">.
Edit: I agree to all comment, i just need one or a little more attribute for my HTML elements. It make sense.

I don't believe there is a universal attribute selector.

you cannot do this and I am pretty sure you don't have too much attributes so you can easily list all of them manually
